# Find Number of combinations possible

Tags: java, math, combinations, permutation

There are two letters "X" and "Y".  A String of length N needs to be formed using those two letters.

How many number of combinations that can be possible where N should start with "Y" and no two or more consecutive "X" will be there?

Consider `N = 7`:

I approached the solution in the following manner:

**My Solution**:

*[No. of combinations that start with letter "Y"] -[No:of combinations containing two consecutive X(n-1 possibilities) + No: of Combinations containing 3 consecutive X(n-1 possibilities)+.....]*

```
=Math.pow(2,N-1)-[(N-2)(N-1)/2];
```

The problem is with the part I'm subtracting. Where I'm missing the elements which contains two consecutive "X" and total of 3 Xs in the String.  Similarly 2 consecutive and total of 4 Xs.
I want to find a generic formula for finding no of Strings that are possible where no 'R' or more consecutive "X" will occur.

Please help me to find the solution for this.

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this theoretical or can you post some code to test?

Comment: code will be single statement to calculate the combinations as the line wrote above. @JNYRanger

Comment: Thanks @Jon I'm not aware of this.Will post there.

Comment: Gotcha.  I see what you're doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should belong to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `R = 1`, similar to Fibonacci.

```
F(0) = F(1) = 1
F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2)
```

Best solution in Java.

```
static int func(int n) {
    if (n < 1) return 0;   // as you required, F(0) = 0
    int n1 = 1, n2 = 1;    // however, for F(2..) we must have F(0) = 1
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int n0 = n1 + n2;
        n2 = n1;
        n1 = n0;
    }
    return n1;
}
```

To generalize the solution for `R` as the number of consecutive `'X'` characters allowed, you would simply sum `R + 1` previous elements in the sequence. As we have seen, for `R = 1` the formula is `F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2)`; now for `R = 2` the formula is `F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2) + F(N-3)`.

Thus we derive a function which takes any `N` and `R`.

```
static int func(int n, int r) {
    if (n < 1) return 0;   // as you required, F(0) = 0
    if (n == 1 || r < 1) return 1;
    int[] a = new int[r + 1];
    a[r] = a[r-1] = 1;     // however, for F(2..) we must have F(0) = 1
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int x = a[0];
        for (int j = 1; j <= r; j++) {
            x += a[j];
            a[j-1] = a[j];
        }
        a[r] = x;
    }
    return a[r];
}
```

Comment: `func(3)` returns 4 but it must be 3 such that `YXY`, `YYY`, `YYX`

Comment: @gknicker `YXX` is not a valid sequence because it has two consecutive `X`

Comment: ok thanks I misread - changed my answer - solution is simply a modified fibonacci

Comment: @gnicker recurrence seems correct to me but `func(0)` must return `0` not `1` because we can't have a combination that starts with `Y` when `n` is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It is wokring of combinations with no two or more consecutive ones.Wat if i have to genralize to 'R' or more consecutive "X"?

Comment: See my edit. Generalized function takes both `N` and `R` parameters.